# Saving triangle object in a list and paint again

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, shapes

I am trying to save the triangle I drew and draw again while the previous triangle is still there. I did this in rectangle, square, circle and ellipse and it worked. I don't know why it won't in Triangle. Is there something wrong in the code?

> This is how I draw and "save (not working)"

**Shape Class**

```
    public void DrawTriangle(Color c, int stroke,PointF[] tpoints, float w, Graphics g)
    {
        this.width = w;
        this.strokeThickness = stroke;
        this.tPoints = tpoints;
        g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.High;
        g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        g.DrawPolygon(new Pen(c, stroke), tpoints);
    }
```

**Form 1**

```
    public void DrawTriangle()
    {
        tC = Color.Red;
        strokeTriangle = trackBar_Stroke.Value;
        tW = Convert.ToInt32((Convert.ToInt32(tbox_Width.Text) * 96) / 25.4);
        tH = (Convert.ToInt32((tW * (Math.Sqrt(3))) / 2));
        tX = (pictureBox_Canvass.Width - tW) / 2;
        tY = ((pictureBox_Canvass.Width - (tH)) / 2) + tH;

        float angle = 0;
        t_Points[0].X = tX;
        t_Points[0].Y = tY;
        t_Points[1].X = (float)(tX + tW * Math.Cos(angle));
        t_Points[1].Y = (float)(tY + tW * Math.Sin(angle));
        t_Points[2].X = (float)(tX + tW * Math.Cos(angle - Math.PI / 3));
        t_Points[2].Y = (float)(tY + tW * Math.Sin(angle - Math.PI / 3));
    }
    public void AcceptTriangle()
    {
        Shape shape = new Shape();
        tC = Color.Gray;
        shape.strokeThickness = strokeTriangle;
        shape.width = tW;
        shape.x = tX;
        shape.y = tY;
        shape.tPoints = t_Points;
        s._triangle.Add(shape);
    }

 s.DrawTriangle(tC, strokeTriangle,t_Points, tX, tY, tW, e.Graphics);
```

> This is how I iterate it.

```
public List<Shape> _triangle = new List<Shape>();
foreach(Shape shapes3 in s._triangle)
        {
            shapes3.DrawTriangle(shapes3.color, shapes3.strokeThickness, shapes3.tPoints, shapes3.width, e.Graphics);
        }
```

Comment: How did you do that for Rectangle and why you cannot use the same solution for Triangle? What's the problem in the code which you shared?

Comment: I told you that  _Doesn't work_ is not a helpful problem description when just posted the exact same question yesterday. - Did you look at the data to check if they are triangles? Maybe you overwrite the same array all the time? We don't see it!! To test replace `this.tPoints = tpoints;` by `this.tPoints = tpoints.ToArray();` !

Comment: @TaW but that really is my question, this process I'm trying with triangle - saving its object and iterating it, worked on other shapes. I don't know what I'm doing wrong here. Please bear with me.

Comment: Did you try my suggestion? Also: What happens? Nothing? Errors? (Which?) Crashes? Wrong results? (Which?)

Comment: nothing happens. @TaW

Comment: I just asked two questions and you answer only one. Rather unpolite, imo.

Comment: Nothing happens, so nothing to answer on the second part. lol

Comment: I gave you a code fragment in my 1st comment. Did you test it??? Also: Did you use the debugger to test the data when saving and when re-drawing??

Comment: Of course, It tried it. How the hell would I knoe if it doesn't work if I didn't. And YES

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Accepting the Triangle (Saving to the list)**

```
var triangle = new Shape
                {
                    strokeThickness = strokeTriangle,
                    color = tC,
                    tPoints = t_Points.ToArray(),
                    x=tX,
                    y=tY,
                    width = tW,
                };
                s._triangle.Add(triangle);
```

**Iterating through the list**

```
foreach(Shape shapes3 in s._triangle)
        {
            shapes3.DrawTriangle(shapes3.color, shapes3.strokeThickness,shapes3.tPoints.ToArray(), shapes3.x, shapes3.y, shapes3.width, e.Graphics);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

At two points in your code you write an array assignment like this.:

```
this.tPoints = tpoints;
```

.. and this:

```
shape.tPoints = t_Points;
```

It is a common error to assume that this creates an array with data. **It doesn't.** All it does is make an array variable **point** to an array that was there before.

The data are **not** duplicated. So when you overwrite the data or clear them the 'new' array now points to the changed or cleared data.

So **all** your objects have the very **same** points.

To correct create actual **copies** of the data!

The simplest way is to add a `ToArray()` call like this:

```
this.tPoints = tpoints.ToArray();
```

.. and this:

```
shape.tPoints = t_Points.ToArray();
```

---

To reiterate:

```
int[] p1 = new int[2] { 23, 42 };   // Now we have one array.
int[] p2 = new int[2] { 3, 2 };    // Now we have two arrays.
p2 = p1;                 //  Now we have only one array again.
p2[1]=1234;             // Now p1[1] is 1234
```